# Why is defaultdict creating an array for my values?

Tags: python

I'm creating a `defaultdict` from an array of arrays:

```
>>> array = [['Aaron','1','2'],['Ben','3','4']]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in array:
...     d[i[0]].append({"num1":i[1],"num2":i[2]})
```

My expected outcome is:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Aaron': {'num1': '1', 'num2': '2'}, 
'Ben': {'num1': '3', 'num2': '4'}})
```

But my outcome is:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Aaron': [{'num1': '1', 'num2': '2'}], 
'Ben': [{'num1': '3', 'num2': '4'}]})
```

It is as if `defaultdict` is trying to keep my values in an array because that is the source list!

Anyone know what's going on here and how I can get my expected outcome?

Comment: Because you asked it to ;)

Comment: @delnan I suspected that "list" might have been the issue. Ill post up the correct code once Ive figured it out just for integrity. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you call this:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

It means that if you attempt to access `d['someKey']` and it does not exist, `d['someKey']` is initialized by calling `list()` with no arguments.  So you end up with an empty list, which you then append your dictionary to.  You probably want this instead:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
```

and then this:

```
for a, b, c in array: 
  d[a].update({"num1": b, "num2": c})
```

Comment: don't forget `from collections import defaultdict` to make answer self contained.

Answer (score 8):

You need a plain dictionary here, not a `defaultdict`:

```
d = {}
for name, num1, num2 in array:
    d[name] = {"num1": num1, "num2": num2}
```

or using a dictionary comprehension

```
d = {name: {"num1": num1, "num2": num2} for name, num1, num2 in array}
```

This code results in `d` being

```
{'Aaron': {'num1': '1', 'num2': '2'}, 'Ben': {'num1': '3', 'num2': '4'}}
```

A `defaultdict(list)` creates an empty list if you access a non-existent key.

Answer (score -1):

Do

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
```

Comment: You're dropping into a decade-old question to tell the OP to do what they're _already doing_ and which does what they don't want.